# How to prove $1 + \frac{n}{2} \le S_{2^n}\le 1 + n$, where $n \in \mathbb {N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, induction

Let $S_j = 1 + \frac {1}{2} + \dots + \frac {1}{j}$, where $j \in \mathbb {N}$.

Prove $1 + \frac{n}{2} \le S_{2^n}\le 1 + n$, where $n \in \mathbb {N}$.

I tried to use induction for this proof but got nowhere. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Try changing the denominators to the next power of $2$ up (and then try  down).  So with $n=3$ look at  $1+\frac12 +\frac14 +\frac14 +\frac18 +\frac18 +\frac18+\frac18$ and look at $1+\frac12 +\frac12 +\frac14 +\frac14 +\frac14 +\frac14+\frac18$

Comment: It's beautiful!

Comment: The usual notation for $S_j$ is $H_j$ (the $j$-th harmonic number) and both the inequalities $H_{2^j}\leq j+1$ and $H_{2^j}\geq 1+\frac{j}{2}$ have been asked many times on MSE , even if not in the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The base case $n = 1$ is obvious. For the inductive step, $S_{2^{n+1}} - S_{2^n}$ is a sum of $2^n$ terms that are all at least $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ and at most $\frac{1}{2^n}$ (the same idea as in Henry's comment), so $\frac{1}{2} \leq S_{2^{n+1}} - S_{2^n} \leq 1$.